# Get printer trays and paperSource by selected printerName

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, avalonia

I am having a ListBox where I show all the printer I can find on the windows client.

```
List<MyPrinterClass> lstPrinters = new List<MyPrinterClass>();

foreach (var item in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
{
    MyPrinterClass d = new MyPrinterClass();
    d.printerName = item.ToString();

    lstPrinters.Add(d);
}
```

If needed my class so far

```
public class MyPrinterClass
{
    public string imageSource { get; set; }
    public Bitmap imageBmp { get; set; }
    public string printerName { get; set; }
    public List<PaperSource> paperSources { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to get the trays and if possible (by the printer) the containing paperSource. The printers have to be installed on the client (its a given condition to my solution). So the details  of trays and paperSource should be known by Windows.

What I tried:
By PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters I am able to get the printerNames but there seems to be no access to other data.
by PrinterSettings.PaperSources I am able to receive the PaperSources but I am coming from a PrintDocument. So the data isnt related to the selected installed printer from my ListBox.

What I expected:
A printer class similar to the [universal windows solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/printing/) given by the MS Guides.

What I could do:
I could create a universal windows solution and hand over the data but its my least favorite option to do so.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use the WPF library and use the Winforms library instead? You should try to use the System.Printing namespace instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use the WPF library ([`System.Printing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing?view=windowsdesktop-8.0)) instead of the Winforms library (`System.Drawing.Printing`).

Use the [`PrintCapabilities`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.printcapabilities?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) and [`PrintQueue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.printqueue?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) to inspect the defaults or to get the current print job in order to get/set the current job's settings via the [`PrintTicket`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.printticket?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) (e.g. page size, copy count etc.).
Use the [`LocalPrintServer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.localprintserver?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) constructor overload in case you want to configure a printer.
Use `PrintServer` to access a remote printer.

```cs
var printServer = new LocalPrintServer();

/* Select a destination printer using one of the following methods */
PrintQueue destinationPrinter;

// Filter list of available printers
PrintQueueCollection availablePrinters = printServer.GetPrintQueues();
destinationPrinter = availablePrinters.First(pq => pq.Name.Contains("PDF", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

// Use the default printer
destinationPrinter = printServer.DefaultPrintQueue;

// Pick a particular printer by name e.g., native PDF printer
destinationPrinter = printServer.GetPrintQueue("Microsoft Print to PDF");

// Print a document (FlowDocument, FixedDocument or from a path)
XpsDocumentWriter documentWriter = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(destinationPrinter);
documentWriter.WriteAsync(fixedDocument);

// Get the current print job settings...
PrintJobSettings jobSettings = destinationPrinter.CurrentJobSettings;

// ... and for example, use it to get the current print ticket
PrintTicket printTicket = jobSettings.CurrentPrintTicket;

// Via the PrintTicket you get various information about the print job
// for example, the current paper tray (input bin).
//
// Test for the default paper tray (input bin)
if (printTicket.InputBin == InputBin.Cassette)
{ 
}

// Get a list of available paper trays for the current printer (PrintQueue)
// by using the PrintCapabilities 
PrintCapabilities printerCapabilities = destinationPrinter.GetPrintCapabilities();
ReadOnlyCollection<InputBin> availablePaperTrays = printerCapabilities.InputBinCapability;
```